# How to retrieve/read/get the location(lat & log) in sqlite database and show in the google map marker?

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps, location

I have the sqlite database of 100 quantity shored in table:the colums are id,latitude,longitude and place condition.

My place condition are: Excellent, Good, Fair and Bad.
If I text  "Good" in my edittext box and press Button, it should show all the "Good" location in Google Map with marker and also all the 100 location.

If I select "Excellent" in my AutoCompleteTextView and press Show Map Button. It Should show the location of my "Excellent" only with Marker i.e ID . Example I select "Good", Show the location for ID 2,8,& 9.Please Help me How can I write a code in Android Studio.

ID  Condition   Latitude    Longitude
1   Excellent   12.897485   15.425974
2   Good        12.897485    15.425974
3   Excellent   12.897485   15.425974
4   Poor        12.897485   15.425974
5   Poor       12.897485    15.425974
6   Excellent   12.897485   15.425974
7   Fair       12.897485    15.425974
8   Good       12.897485    15.425974
9   Good       12.897485    15.425974
10  Excellent   12.897485   15.425974

How can I write a code for this to read all the location ,which is already stored in sqlite db.

I know this question may asked ,But i was not clear for beginners .

Comment: For the beginners, I think you can try to use `Database browser` for `Sqlite` [here](http://sqlitebrowser.org). I think you can just select some lines, and the SQL will be pop up.

Comment: But How to do in Android studio??? I appreciate your remark.I think link may help me.

Comment: Take look at [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#ReadDbRow).

Comment: Example I select "Good", Show the location for ID 2,8,& 9.Please Help me How can I write a code in Android Studio.                        ID Condition  Latitude          Longitude
1 Excellent 12.897485 15.425974
2 Good 12.897485 15.425974
3 Excellent 12.897485 15.425974
4 Poor         12.897485         15.425974
5 Poor 12.897485 15.425974
6 Excellent  12.897485 15.425974
7 Fair         12.897485  15.425974
8 Good 12.897485 15.425974
9 Good 12.897485 15.425974
10 Excellent 12.897485 15.425974

Comment: I am using the MapActivity with AutoCompleteTextView, Button, and Map Fragment. Mapactivity.xml file attached
I want to filter my location using the AutoCompleteTextView.My sqlite database consists in above comments: